# JS/ExtendScript - Extract/Collect/RePackage a chosen button/function and all dependancies?

Tags: javascript, function, extendscript

I have a complicated script with a lot of buttons & functions. Is there a way to identify a chosen function and then automatically extract it from the script along with all other functions & variables etc it relies on?

Comment: Is this a script you have the source code to?

Comment: @stib yes, that's right.